# parse google place json with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

for any reason this code doesn't seem to work

```
var request = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
request = request + "location="+lat+","+lng+"&";
request = request + "radius=500&";
request = request + "types=&";
request = request + "name=&";
request = request + "sensor=false&";
request = request + "key="+key;

$.getJSON(request, function(data){ alert(data); });
```

The string is valid and i get the result if i just load it in my browser. Do you see anything wrong here?

EDIT: alright, problem solved. The Google Places API actually does not accept ajax jsonp calls. I'll have to use their javascript API instead. See this thread for more details:

[How do I use Google Places to get an array of Place names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159246/how-do-i-use-google-places-to-get-an-array-of-place-names)

---

Thanks for your replies. So I now make the API call with the following code:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
        location:lat+","+lng,
        radius:500,
        types:"",
        name:"",
        sensor:"false",
        key:key
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Whiich doesn't show any alert box. By inspecting the code, I catch an error message:

```
   "html_attributions" : [],
  json:2Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token :
```

"results" : [
      {

However, following this error message, in the console, the requested data actually shows in the "results" field... Any idea?

Comment: This needs some more context; where is this code being executed, and where are `lat`, `lng`, and `key` defined?

Comment: Are you getting a specific error message in the console?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 1):

The Google Places API doesn't support JSONP requests.

Comment: Great to know but a reference would be wonderful for more information.

Comment: @agrothe You can't proof that something is absent with reference, like the god for example.