# Reading the json file from google maps places api (with javascript or php)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I am building an application in which i am trying to fetch the list of places near to a given lat and long.

i got a api key and entering this on my browser url works and gives me a json file with the places data.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAImBQiqvaXOQtqeK8VC-9I96kMmB6Mz7I
```

but when i try to fetch and parse it though j query its not giving me anything.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAImBQiqvaXOQtqeK8VC-9I96kMmB6Mz7I',
 function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

i found the following questions on stack overflow but they dint reach me to an answer.

[parse google place json with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155448/parse-google-place-json-with-javascript)

[How do I use Google Places to get an array of Place names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159246/how-do-i-use-google-places-to-get-an-array-of-place-names)

**EDIT:**

i tried to get contents of the file using php by

```
echo file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAImBQiqvaXOQtqeK8VC-9I96kMmB6Mz7I");
```

and got the file contents using php.

But is there a way to parse this with jquery or javascript ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Check for an update of your WAMP distribution. Common ones have HTTPS available. Which one are you using?

Comment: Related: [How to enable HTTPS stream wrappers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305954/how-to-enable-https-stream-wrappers) (WAMP as well)

Comment: On my windows box I don't have a problem with the default PHP available from php.net using the HTTPS Stream wrapper (PHP 5.3.6). The [wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) needs the openssl extension to be enabled at least. Check if that extension is available and successfully loading.

Comment: i have already changed the line extension=php_openssl.dll in my php.ini .... also tried running <?php var_dump(stream_get_wrappers()); ?>
 but this gives no 'https' in the list..

Comment: Not only uncomment that line but please check as well if the openssl extension is actually loading, e.g. cmd: `php -m` or by executing `phpinfo()`.

Comment: its not loading i guess.. i tried executing the function openssl_pkey_new() and i gave an error **Call to undefined function openssl_pkey_new()**

Comment: If the openssl functions are not available, than the extension does not get loaded. Maybe you're editing the wrong php.ini? I'm not fluent with WampServer.

Comment: i ran echo phpinfo(); in my system and got  **Configuration File (php.ini) Path  C:\WINDOWS  <br/>
Loaded Configuration File  C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\bin\php.ini** i edited the second one. Couldnt locate the first.

Comment: Second one is fine. Enable PHP error logging as well and check if the error log give's you an error/reason why the library is not loading. Maybe that's inside the apache error log as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible using ajax (directly) cross domain request are not allowed. I've tried:

```
echo file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAImBQiqvaXOQtqeK8VC-9I96kMmB6Mz7I");
```

it works for me (wamp 2.0 openssl enabled).

if you succeed in this, you can get the content using your ajax script on the page in the same domain.

EDIT:

The idea is to do an ajax call to your php page, the php page gets data from de google api and returns it. jquery automatically parses json :)

in code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'url_to_your_php',
  data: {
    location:'-33.8670522,151.1957362',
    radius:500,
    sensor:false,
    key:'AIzaSyAImBQiqvaXOQtqeK8VC-9I96kMmB6Mz7I'},
  dataType: "json"
  type: "GET", //or POST if you want => update your php in that case
  success: function( data ) {
    for(var i in data.results){
       doSomthingWithYourLocation(data.results[i]);
    }
  },
  error: function (request, status, error) {
    //handle errors
  }
});
```

Your php shoud do somthing like this:

```
<?php 
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?" .
      "location=-" . $_GET['location'] .
      "&radius=" . $_GET['radius'] .
      "&sensor=" . $_GET['sensor'] .
      "&key=" .$_GET['key']);
?>
```

It is probably best to check the input in the php files but this should work.

Comment: yup.. but open ssl also is not getting loaded.. i uncommented the php.ini line. Any thing else tobe done. Or shall i reinstall the wamp. How can i install with open ssl enabled?

Answer (score 2):

A script loaded from one domain can't make an ajax request to another domain. Use the Google Maps JavaScript api to load your data.

Comment: i tried the codes in the below link http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html ..in **Place Search Requests** where to get the places near by we need to have a map initiated first.   'service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.search(request, callback);'  .. can this be converted to a request which without initiating maps.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not possible. The idea of the Maps API is to use Maps, not to get free information from Google. BTW, the terms of service (http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/maps/terms.html) say: "You must not use or display the Content without a corresponding Google map, unless you are explicitly permitted to do so in the Maps APIs Documentation". Accessing the API through PHP is a violation of the TOS.

Comment: But im getting the data thought the file url i gave in the question. My problem is to parse it by either php or javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The places javascript API can be accessed here:   http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your object data this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAImBQiqvaXOQtqeK8VC-9I96kMmB6Mz7I', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index,place) {
            alert(place.name);
        });
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: did it work in your end? i think it wont work due to **Same origin policy**.. Let me check. :)